# How to add anchor-based URL navigation to jQuery masonry

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tags, anchor

Hello I'm looking for a way to add anchor-based URL navigation to jQuery masonry..

Here's the example:
http://desandro.com/demo/masonry/filtering.html

I'm trying to be able to direct people straight to a filterable class (ie: ../filtering.html#red)

Seems like there should be an easy solution but I'm a Javanoob so I would really appreciate some help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the code on that page (after it, still in `document.ready`) you could do this:

```
$("#filtering-nav a[href='" + location.hash + "']").click();
```

This just performs a click on the `<a href="#red">` when you go to `page.htm#red` for example.

Or, if you want them immediately hidden, do this:

```
var myClass = location.hash.replace('#','.');
$("#primary").children().not(myClass).addClass('invis').hide();
$('#primary').masonry();
```

This doesn't require the filtering buttons, it just hides anything not matching the class in the hash, like this: `page.htm#classToShow`.